# Asterisk : originate call doesn't set the CALLERID in the dialplan

Tags: sip, asterisk

I am using Asterisk PBX to call a softphone, i use thise command : "originate SIP/100 extension 4004" , in the dialplan, I have to get the CALLERID variable, but in this case, it's always empty!

P.S : if i call the extension (4004), from the softphone(100), the CALLERID is set, and I can get it with : `${CALLERID(num)}`.

How to get the caller id in the originate case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the final solution i am using now :

- i call my extention from a php script (originate SIP/100 extension 777)
- i write my extension to a text file (file_put_contents)
- then i read it in the asterisk dial plan, and set this variable as the caller ID Set(CALLERID(num)=${caller_id}

i didn't find another solution.

Answer (score 11):

When you're originating a call, you set the Caller ID yourself.  There are two ways of doing this - either in the originate application yourself, or in the dialplan.  An example of this is below.

```
Action: Originate
Channel: local/12345@outgoing
Application: Echo
CallerID: Asterisk <12345>
```

extensions.conf:

```
[outgoing]
exten => 12345,1,NoOp()
same => n,Verbose(1, Outgoing Caller ID: {$CALLERID(all)})
same => n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
same => n,Hangup()
```

or you could do something like:

```
exten => 12345,1,NoOp()
same => n,Set(CALLERID(num)=54321)
same => n,Set(CALLERID(name)=Asterisk)
same => n,Verbose(1, Outgoing Caller ID: {$CALLERID(all)})
same => n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
same => n,Hangup()
```

You should see your caller ID set either in the AMI originate or, if you choose to override it in the dialplan, those values.

For more information, see [Manager Action Originate](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ManagerAction_Originate) and [CallerID Function](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Function_CALLERID).

Comment: hello
thanks for your answer, but i don't see how to use your solution, since the caller id must be dynamic (i call him from a php script wich receive the extention as parameter).

anyway, i am using the same script to write the extention to a file, then i read this file from asterisk with an AGI script, this the solution i work with now.

exten => 4004,n,AGI(get_caller_id.php)
exten => 4004,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=${caller_id})

thanks.

Comment: The example above was answering your question as to how to set the caller ID on a channel that is created via an AMI originate.  I wasn't attempting to write your application for you.  If you need to have a dynamic caller ID, simply use dialplan variables instead of the hard coded values illustrated above, and set the variables from your AGI script.

Comment: i didn't say i am using AMI !! i simply call originate from another script.
thank you anyway :)

Comment: Actually, you never said what you *were* using, nor did you say it *wasn't* AMI.  AMI is what everybody and their dog use to originate calls.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is way late but if your on Asterisk 1.8 the Originate app just does not allow it normally.

I had asked in the forums before and they said that feature would be added at a later point. So what I did was modify the app_originate.c to allow number and name to be passed.

Here is the one I wrote up last year:
https://github.com/cmendes0101/asterisk-originate-callerid

Been in production for over a year and has been working good. Was written for 1.8. It was a easy modification so if your using a different version you can simple diff the changes and make those small changes to your version to make it happen.

Comment: I have the problem too. My asterisk version is 11. I changed the app_originate.c like your code. But it does't set the callerid. Would you please help me.