# Asterisk: callerid is shown as anonymous

Tags: asterisk, vici

I'm trying to use asterisk to dial auto calls, but the problem is that the callerid is shown anonymous in the client device.
so how can I set the callerid to be shown correctly in the client device?

Comment: Can you upload Asterisk log, what type of circuit (SIP, FXO, etc), whats the call flow

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045451/asterisk-originate-call-doesnt-set-the-callerid-in-the-dialplan

Comment: You can't. Vici work that way. For outbound call it will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably originating that call. Two methods are responsible for that:

```
ast_pbx_outgoing_app
ast_pbx_outgoing_exten
```

Based on how the origination is done, you may need to slightly modify *apps/app_originate.c* or *res/res_clioriginate.c*.

If you're using AMI (The Asterisk Manager Interface) to originate the call, you can just simply "Set" the variable *CALLERID(all)* to whatever you want to use.

The **anonymous** is the default value when NULL callerid is passed to one of the functions.